# Can you solve this Calculus temperature decay problem directly without using Calculus?

Tags: calculus, continuity

**The problem is**:

*(The rate of decrease of temperature of an object is continuous and proportional to the difference between the temperature of the object and that of the surrounding medium.)*

*Suppose that the surrounding temperature remains constant. The object is initially at a temperature of $100^\circ$ and loses temperature at the rate of $\frac{1}{100}$ per minute of the difference between its temperature at time $t$ and the constant temperature $T_0$ of the surrounding medium. Derive the formula that relates the temperature of the object and time.*

I can solve the problem by setting up the derivative $\frac{dt}{dT} = -\frac{1}{k \cdot (T-T_0)}$, finding the integral and therefore the function $t(T)$ and then $T(t)$.

**However**, knowing that any continuous growing/decaying process can be expressed as some exponential scaling of $e$ (I think...), I was wondering whether there is a way to come up with the original formula/function $T(t)$ without going through the derivative $\to$ integral process.

If it is, *please explain your thought process for each step you take mentally to come up with the formula*. I already have the answer so it's not what I'm looking for; rather I'm looking for a way to logically and mathematically derive it directly without using calc.

Comment: If you know the solution to $\frac{dy}{dt}=Cy$ is an exponential, then you can take your equation, realize that it is equivalent to $\frac{d(T-T_0)}{dt}=-\frac{1}{k}(T-T_0)$, so $T-T_0$ is an exponentially decaying function.

Comment: I think you need to know at minimum that ${d\over dt}k=0$ for constant $k$ and ${d\over dt}e^{kt}=ke^{kt}$. (And that derivatives mean rates.) Without knowing at least that, you can reason what the function will look like, but I don't think you can get an exact form for it.